# Is Airbus offering to retrofit older A350s with the new winglets?

Tags: airbus, winglets, airbus-a350

I noticed that new winglets (sharklets?) on the A350 are extended as part of the PIP (Performance Improvement Package).

Are older A350s being retrofitted with the new sharklets? Does Airbus even offer that as an option? I'm assuming it's probably not as simple as swapping out sharklets because we're talking about a composite wing here.

Comment: Composite wing doesn't mean that its one-piece. I don't know the answer to this question, but I'm sure the winglets can, at the very least, be removed/replaced.